# Using a custom block

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, controllers

I've created a simple module, purely for the block.

I want to add it to the `newsletter.phtml` file that controls the customers newsletter subscriptions as I need to create custom functionality through my block.

How do I go about adding my custom block to this file or any file?

I'm new to this whole module development, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You want to add your custom block to newsletter section, right?

Comment: Yes, the newsletter subscriptions page in the customer account frontend

Comment: You can override the newsletter block then you can customize it according to your requirement also you can add more public functions to your block which can be used in your newsletter phtml.

Comment: How do I go about overriding the newsletter block?

Answer (score 0):

You may be want to remove  Magento default newsletter .
Then you there are two steps need to call for all your block.

Create `newsletter_manage_index.xml` at  your module folder **`app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}/view/frontend/{layout}/`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <!-- remove defult block -->
       <referenceBlock name="customer_newsletter" remove="true" />

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Block\{YourClassName}" name="customer_newsletter_new" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Customer::form/newsletter.phtml">
                <container name="customer.newsletter.form.before" as="form_before" label="Newsletter Subscription Form Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rewards"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this step.

1. create `newsletter_manage_index.xml` into your custom extension with the code something like this.

> app/code/Vendor/Extension/view/frontend/layout/newsletter_manage_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Extension\Block\Yourblock" name="custom_newsletter" template="Vendor_Extension::yourphtmlfile.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```